# Automatic generation of an x509 certificate by OpenSSL

Tags: bash, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I need to automate X509 SSL certificate generation in a bash script (without prompt any strings to console).

I generate an SSL key and cert request automatically, but I can not automatize certificate generation without promt password.

This commands works without prompt:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:passwd -out testem/2.key 1024

openssl req -new -passin pass:passwd -subj "/" -key testem/2.key -out testem/2.csr
```

This command requests input password:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in testem/2.csr -signkey testem/2.key -out testem/2.crt
```

I can't find the option "-passout" in the manual of the command "x509".

What can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-build-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to supply the password. Like this for example.

```
openssl x509 -passin pass:passwd -req -days 365 -in testem/2.csr -signkey testem/2.key -out testem/2.crt
```